# Create an AWS serverless app in TS with layers

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

after multiple months of struggling with AWS documentation and trying to find any sort of useful info on AWS lambdas I've hit a dead end so I'm asking here.

What I want is really simple and that is to have an app written in Typescript where I have my lambdas that use my layer that is also written in Typescript.

I've found [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-typescript-projects-with-aws-sam-cli/) by AWS where it describes how to use TS for writing a lambda function but it is not detailed enough for use with layers.

The idea is to have lambda call Action inside layer

Examples(might have some typos/wrong indentations/not passing things properly...)

My structure looks like this:

```
.aws-sam
...
src
 Domains
  Users
   CreateUser
    CreateUser.ts
    package.json
    event.json
  ...
Layers
 Shared
  node_modules
  src
   ...
   Services
    Users
     Actions
      CreateUser
       CreateUser.ts
  tsconfig.json
  index.ts
  package.json
tsconfig.json
package.json
.env
...
```

My CloudFormation look like this:

```
...
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    Handler: index.handler
    MemorySize: 1024
    Timeout: 30
    Tracing: Active
    Environment:
      Variables:
        AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: 1
Resources:
  # Main
  Shared:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: Shared
      ContentUri: src/Layers/Shared
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs14.x
  CreateUser:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: CreateUser
      CodeUri: src/Domains/Users/CreateUser
      Handler: CreateUser.handler
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints:
          - CreateUser.ts
      Layers:
        - !Ref Shared
```

My CreateUser lambda:

```
import {logger, CreateUser} from "@shared-layer"

const handler = async (event:any) => {
  await new CreateUser().run()
}

exports.handler = logger(handler);
```

I can't compile this with `sam build` and there is no explanation anywhere on how to make this work.

1. Should I have ts setup in my shared layer or will the main ts pick it up?
2. Should I always put Metadata on every lambda?
3. Do I need a specific Metadata for my layer resource? If yes then what exactly?
4. Is there a way of using imports with paths(like @shared-layers)?
5. Is there any sort of sane documentation regarding AWS because the official one is terrible?

Thank you